# Can We Use .SVG script in Email template to avoide Spam filter?

Tags: email, svg, email-attachments, spam-prevention

We can't use `<img src="http://www.domain.com/images/bull.png">` inside the email template because of spam or junk filtering.

So can we use **svg** graphics script in email template to avoid by spam filtering?

For example:

```
<svg version="1.1" height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
  <path d="M15 0 Q0 0 0 15 T15 30 30 15 15 0" fill="#249B57" stroke="none" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

No. Almost no clients will render it, and if you are sending good content and have a good sending reputation, it won't go in spam anyway.

There is no simple way around spam filters - if there was, spammers would use them and the filters would be useless.

Comment: Actually This is not what i was asking.

Comment: My wp site already sending good contents but sometimes due to  http:// address the users receives in spam or junk 
ex:

$message = 'some contents + svg graphics code'

<? 
    $header .= "Reply-To: Some One <someone@mydomain.com>\r\n"; 
    $header .= "From: Some One <mydomain@myhost.com>\r\n"; 
    $header .= "Organization: My Organization\r\n"; 
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"; 
 
    mail("recipient@recipient-domain.com", $subject, $message", $header); 
?>

Comment: I think the answer was good. It could have stopped after the word "No" but he went on to explain to you why.

Comment: Thanks Kevin - I would have stopped after "no" if SO had let me! There is nothing intrinsically wrong with links in email that will cause messages to end up in spam folders; you're barking up the wrong tree. It's far more likely that it's objecting to *where* you're linking to.